# Roslaunch XML format: is there a DTD?

Tags: roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am developing a ROS plugin for Vim and want to add support for editing of roslaunch files. Vim already has a built-in support for omni-completion of XML dialects as soon as the formal definition of a language is provided. So I am wondering does there exist a DTD for the roslaunch XML format?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60804/roslaunch-xml-format:-is-there-a-dtd?/) by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 260 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-16**:
I don't know if there is, but you could make one yourself.  Would be nice, if you finish this. My complete vim plugin is currently `setfiletype xml`.

**Comment by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) on 2013-04-16**:
Ha-ha yes, `ft=xml` is suprisingly useful :)
For sure I can create DTD myself, but I just hoped to avoid extra work and also simplify maintenance.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-10-17**:
@sergey_alexandrov, if you end up doing this, it would be very useful to use as a basis for linting roslaunch files in roslint.

**Comment by [sergey_alexandrov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1412/sergey_alexandrov/) on 2013-10-17**:
@mikepurvis No, in the end I decided it is not worth the effort, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK there isn't.

One reason is that ROS uses TinyXML for parsing XML files which [does not support DTD](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/):

```
TinyXML doesn't parse or use DTDs (Document Type Definitions) or XSLs (eXtensible Stylesheet Language.)
```

...so ROS tools cannot validate your launch file as they are implemented now. This aside, this would be definitively a very nice contribution.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created an XSD and a DTD. It's on https://gist.github.com/nalt/dfa2abc9d2e3ae4feb82ca5608090387 for now. Feel free to comment.

It looks like the XSD is the better choice.

It works for code completion, highlighting and validation with various tools.

---

Originally posted by [Nicolas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4738/nicolas/) with karma: 41 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrj.fonseca](https://answers.ros.org/users/53624/jrj.fonseca/) on 2020-04-16**:
sory i am new to this i can't install the plugin of sergey, but i want to autocomplete my .launch where do i put your files to my vim autocomplete my launch file